# Is PostGIS documentation correct for ST_Project?

Tags: postgis-2.0, documentation

In example of the page [ST_Project](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_Project.html) the select is

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Project('POINT(0 0)'::geography, 100000, 45));
                  st_astext
    ------------------------------------------
     POINT(0.63523102912532 0.63947233472882)
    (1 row)
```

But, in my enviroment this code give me an error like "Azimuth must be between -2PI and 2PI".

After a few tryings I solve with :

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Project('POINT(0 0)'::geography, 100000, radians(45) ))
```

The sample in page tells the data type expected is in degrees, and the function expects radians.

Am I using the wrong PostGIS version?

My PostGIS version : 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consult [how to report documentation issues](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch14.html#id753688). I have the same behavior.

POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.8" TOPOLOGY RASTER

Answer (score 3):

I have updated the documentation and just a heads up the new doc location is at

http://postgis.net/documentation

For this specific:

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_Project.html